# howto run a bash compressed script?

Tags: bash, gzip

There is a way to run compressed bash script with 'arguments' directly on the fly without decompressing it in a file and then running the decompressed file ?

for example: i need to execute the setup-mysql gzip compressed script with some given arguments: "-n", "wordpress", "locahost", without decompressing the script first and then executing.

What i'm looking for is a replacement of the word MAGIC... in my command below:

```
gzip -d --stdout /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql.gz | MAGIC... -n wordpress localhost
```

Comment: you are looking for `xargs` or `cat`.

Comment: @arkascha maybe xargs can do it, but i failed to append arguments of my script

Comment: @janos no, i'm just looking to execute an already compressed script on the fly without decompressing it on a named file and then executing this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gzip -d --stdout file.gz | bash -s -- "-n wordpress localhost"
```

A little explanation: with `bash -s` you're telling bash to process `stdin` as commands. The double dash means that everything that follows will be passed as arguments (a single dash seems to be equivalent, check `man bash`).

If you didn't have any arguments to pass you could just do

```
gzip -d --stdout file.gz | bash
```

Another option is:

```
gzip -d --stdout file.gz | bash /dev/stdin "arguments"
```

Comment: `... bash -s -- -n wordpress localhost` would be better, so that the script sees each argument separately, rather than a single word.

Comment: @jlhonora, thinks, that what's i'm looking for, but why you say that's machine-dependent ?

Comment: @Zskdan I finally dropped that comment since I couldn't back it up with any references. I just thought that '/dev/stdin' may not be present or not readable in certain machines and linux distros, but that not seems to be the case.

Comment: @jlhonora `bash` implements those aliases internally if those files aren't actually present in the file system.