# Execute the content of binary from a pipe

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, executable

In short, [howto run a bash compressed script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916879/howto-run-a-bash-compressed-script), but can this be done with a binary, instead of a shell script?

---

Suppose I have a binary which is compressed into a .gz.  I can unzip to a pipe and examine the contents thus:

```
$ gzip -d --stdout hello.gz | file -
/dev/stdin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
$
```

Instead of piping this output to a command, is there any way I can actually execute the contents of the pipe itself, without writing it to a file?

I considered using a named pipe, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$ mkfifo execpipe
$ chmod 777 execpipe
$ gzip -d --stdout hello.gz > execpipe &
[3] 30034
$ ./execpipe 
bash: ./execpipe: Permission denied
$ [3]+  Broken pipe             gzip -d --stdout hello.gz >execpipe

$
```

Is there a way to execute the contents of a pipe without creating an actual file?

Comment: `Permission denied` what if you try to sudo?

Comment: Whatever pgm you are piping it into would have to be more or less the equivalent of the OS loader that loads pgms, resolves, addresses, sets ups memory segments, etc.

Comment: @Samoth - `sudo` fails with "sudo: ./execpipe: command not found".  Running under `su` also fails with "bash: ./execpipe: Permission denied"

Comment: Best you can do is dump it into a file in a ramfs or tmpfs and execute it.

Comment: I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665271/how-can-i-make-bash-execute-an-elf-binary-from-stdin?rq=3) answers OP's question most thoroughly: On Linux, executing binaries relies on a system call which will only accept a file as input. (Of course the file can be temporary, e.g. live in `/dev/shm` or some other tmpfs, like @ZanLynx mentioned.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the answer is no.

You can execute a file manually by passing it to the [Linux loader](http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/), which will be named something like `/lib/ld-linux.so`.<sup>*</sup> It needs an actual file, though. It can't execute a pipe or stdin; it needs to be able to `mmap()` the file.

```
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/true
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 - < /bin/true
-: error while loading shared libraries: -: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 <(cat /bin/true)
/dev/fd/63: error while loading shared libraries: /dev/fd/63: invalid ELF header
```

<sup>* On my Red Hat machine it's `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (32-bit) or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (64-bit). On my Ubuntu machine it's `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.</sup>