# How can I make bash execute an ELF binary from stdin?

Tags: bash, pipeline, execution

For some obscure reason I have written a bash script which generates some source code, then compiles it, using

```
... whatever ... | gcc -x c -o /dev/stdout
```

Now, I want to execute the result on the compilation. How can I make that happen? No use of files please.

Comment: bash doesn't execute files at all, the kernel does -- and the syscalls used require content to be stored in files.

Comment: ...I'm not saying "can't possibly be done", but without at least using a language with mmap support and a C foreign function interface, you're going to have a very bad time. As in, the kind of bad time that might as well be "can't possibly be done".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I know bash doesn't execute binaries "itself", don't split hairs please...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is not splitting hairs, he's explaining why your approach won't work.

Comment: The hairs are important. If bash included a dynamic linker, what you're requesting would be more feasible.

Comment: BTW, what's the real goal? If you just want to execute C at runtime, [the `tcc` compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/) can do that out-of-the-box.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That actually is the real goal :-) I need to run something small that I can't distribute as a binary as part of the build process of something larger. Anyway, TCC is great  - just noticed its existence - but most people don't have it installed, unfortunately.

Comment: That being the case, there's a huge amount of prior art -- build systems do this kind of thing all the time. And if you look at how... they write such interim pieces to disk.

Comment: That said, speaking as someone who's been in charge of porting and packaging for an embedded Linux distro, please don't write software that can only be compiled that way. Keep in mind that cross-compilation is a thing that exists -- folks who are compiling software for Embedded System A will typically be doing builds on a high-performance cluster of Commodity System B boxen. If you can only compile your software if the compiler is running on the target, you just made peoples' lives very unpleasant, especially if that target maxes out at 8MB of RAM.

Comment: (`perl` is a particularly bad offender on this count -- the number of man-hours I spent convincing the perl interpreter to cross compile despite its insistence on running little platform tests throughout the process -- as opposed to all at once up-front with an easy override mechanism the way `autoconf` and friends do -- is still a source of regret).

Comment: Compiled binaries are loaded with the help of a binary interpreter. If you run `readelf -l /bin/ls | grep interpreter`, for example, you'll see that it is requesting `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. In reality, it is similar to running, and please try it, `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/ls` (this is assuming you are running 64bit linux). The problem you have now is that `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` does not read from `stdin`. You can run `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on its own and it'll give you a usage message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charles Duffy said, to execute a binary, you'd have to tell your operating system (which seems to be a Unix variant) to load and execute something – and Unix systems only take files to execute them directly.

What you could do is have a process that prepares a memory region containing the ELF binary, fork and jump into that region - but even that is questionable, considering that there's CPU support to suppress *exactly* that operation (R^X). Basically, what you need is a runtime linker, and shells do not (and also: should not) include something like that.

Let's drop the Bash requirement (which really just sounds like you're trying to find an obvious hole in an application that is older than I am grumpy):

Generally, requiring ELF (which is a *file* format) and avoiding *files* at the same time is a tad complicated. GCC generates machine code. If you just want to execute known machine code, put it into some buffer, build a function pointer to that and call it. Simple as that. However, you'd obviously don't have all the nice relocation and dynamic linking that the process of executing an ELF binary or loading a shared object (`dlopen`) would have.

If you want that, I'd look in the direction of things like LLVM – I know, for a fact, that there's people building "I compile C++ at runtime and execute it" with LLVM as executing instance, and clang as compiler. In the end, what your `gcc|something` is is really just JIT – an old technology :)

Comment: I don't really care about it being ELF; I only want something that a C compiler (could be clang I guess) can emit.

Comment: @einpoklum, with respect to compromises -- how important is the *bash* part? Putting something written in C or Python (or a great many other dynamic languages) on the right-hand side of the pipe would suffice, albeit potentially with more work than I'm willing to do to build an answer. (As I told you back before I got scolded for hairsplitting -- the requirements probably look a lot like "mmap support and a C foreign function interface").

Comment: also, "putting something on the right side of the `|`" really isn't easier than writing your ELF to a file.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to not write to the filesystem at all, then neither `bash` nor any other UNIX program will be able to help you execute an ELF from a pipe - [`execve`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) only takes a path to a regular file as its `filename` and will fail (setting `errno` to `EACCES`) if you pass it a special file (device or named pipe) or a directory.

However, if your goal is to keep the executable entirely in RAM and not touch the hard disk (perhaps because the disk is read-only) you can do something with the same effect on your machine by using [`tmpfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html), which comes with many UNIX-like systems (and is used in Linux to implement semaphores) and allows you to create a full-permissions filesystem that resides entirely in RAM:

```
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=10M tmpfs /mnt/mytmpfs
```

You can then write your binary to that:

```
... whatever ... | gcc -x c -o /mnt/mytmpfs/program.out
/mnt/mytmpfs/program.out
```

and `bash` will load it for you as if it was on disk.

Note, however, that you do still need enough RAM onboard the device to store and execute the program - though due to the nature of most executable binaries, you would need that anyway.

If you don't want to leave the program behind on your ramdisk (or normal disk, if that is acceptable) for others to find, you can also delete the file immediately after starting to execute it:

```
/mnt/mytmpfs/program.out &
rm /mnt/mytmpfs/program.out
```

The name will disappear immediately, but the process will internally hold a hard link to that file, then release that hard link when it terminates, allowing the file to be immediately deleted from disk. (However, the storage won't actually be freed until the program exits, and the program will not be able to `exec` itself either).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years. And now you can execute C, C++ code and Crap from the command line interactively, in a read-eval-print loop (REPL). The TCC compiler [a tiny and fast compiler](https://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git/) has long been able to compile and execute a string from the command line. Shameless plugs. I contributed the patch for `mmap` support to make TCC's string compilation compatible with SELinux.

The REPL is a fork of IGCC for which I added TCC support and Crap. [Find it here](https://github.com/themanyone/itcc). Have fun testing code snippets, and seeing instant results.

Example:

```
   $ ./itcc
   tcc> int a = 5;
   tcc> a -= 2;
   tcc> if (a < 4) {
   ['-:16: error: identifier expected']
   tcc>    printf("a is %i\n", a);
   ['-:17: error: identifier expected']
   tcc> }
   a is 3
   tcc> |
```

Comment: I told the OP about tcc [in a comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665271/how-can-i-make-bash-execute-an-elf-binary-from-stdin#comment68562704_40665271) back when it was first written.

Comment: Right, he may inspect the open source code of TCC and see how it works.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to drop the REPL aspect and show to take code from the standard input and execute it? Also, please say a few words about the compatibility of itcc and gcc (or clang if you like) in terms of features, language standard versions etc. Also, I really don't want to get those errors.

Comment: _nod_. [Their response at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665271/how-can-i-make-bash-execute-an-elf-binary-from-stdin#comment68562949_40665271), as far as I can tell, was to the effect that they were intending to accomplish the stated goal _using only widely-installed software_ and thus that they considered tcc unacceptable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : That's true, but 7 years have passed; plus, not all readers may have the same interests. Still, you have a point, hellork is kind of stealing your thunder...